# (SETF L (FLATTEN L)) should be a lambda expression error

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

So I am trying to code a common lisp function that takes a list uses a predefined function function flatten (that works I've tested and all) and returns a flattened list without duplicates. However I keep getting this error: %EXPAND-FORM: (SETF L (FLATTEN L)) should be a lambda expression
and I don't know how to fix it.

```
(defun eliminateDuplicates (L)
  ((setf L (flatten L))
     (cond ((null L) L)
          ((member (car L) (cdr L))
            (eliminateDuplicates (cdr L)))
             (t (cons (car L) (eliminateDuplicates (cdr L)))))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have too many parentheses:

```
((setf ... ...) ...)
```

When a form looks like this in a normal evaluation context (e.g. not a binding):

```
(F X)
```

And if `F` is not a macro, then `F` should be a function, either a symbol naming an existing function or a lambda expression, `(lambda (y) ...)`. Here, `F` is not a lambda expression because it is `(setf ... ...)`.

Note also that since you call the function recursively, you'll keep calling `flatten` on each sublist of the list. You may want to split your functions in two, one that remove duplicates on a flattened list, and one that calls the first on `(flatten L)`. For example you could rewrite it as follows (please note how symbols are separated with dashes (not uppercased letters), and how the code is formatted):

```
(defun eliminate-duplicates (list)
  (when list
    (destructuring-bind (head . rest) list
      (if (member head rest)
          (eliminate-duplicates rest)
          (cons head (eliminate-duplicates rest))))))

(defun flatten-eliminate-duplicates (list)
  (eliminate-duplicates (flatten list)))
```

Note also that in both branches of the `if`, you call the `eliminate-duplicates` function recursively. You may as well compute it outside of the `if`, and bind it to some variable. The resulting list has either the same number of elements, or *less*. It might be a bit more efficient to call `member` on that list instead, since it might be shorter.

```
(defun eliminate-duplicates (list)
  (when list
    (let ((rest (eliminate-duplicates (rest list))))
      (if (member head rest) rest (cons head rest)))))
```

(you could also use a `hash-table` but maybe that's out of scope for your needs)